# Creating user account in moodle using only mobile numbers

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

Users in low-resource settings do not have email ids. I'm looking into external systems wherein users can easily create an account using mobile numbers, or log in using their mobile number and password. #moodlemobile #moodle

Please let me know the possibilities.

Comment: Couple of ideas here https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/No_Email

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to create a local plugin that allows the user to sign up with custom fields. Once your form submits the data you need you can add it all to an stdClass object and pass it like this:

```
$usernew->id = user_create_user($usernew, false, false);
```

The second parameter is for password update and the third is for triggering events.

Keep in mind that you still have to provide the mandatory fields for the user and if you want the user to be able to add their own picture you'll have to handle it yourself, too.

Comment: Can you pls share the GitHub link as a sample?

Comment: I'm not on GitHub, unfortunately.